# Using object in JSP with Spring 4.0.7

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm trying to send object in a SpringController to the client. But it doesn't work.

I've read the same questions a bunch of times, but couldn't figure it out.

Here is my code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/departs/{from}")
public class NextTrainController {

/** Handle nextTrains request with a destination specified */
@RequestMapping(value = "/{to}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getNextTrainsToDestination(@PathVariable String from, @PathVariable String to,
        @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Date date, Model model) {
    // Date null means we leave now
    if (date == null)
        date = new Date();

    /* debug */
    List<TransilienTrain> trains = new ArrayList<TransilienTrain>(5);

    TransilienTrain train = new TransilienTrain();
    train.setMission("VIK30");
    trains.add(train);

    train = new TransilienTrain();
    train.setMission("KOOPA34");
    trains.add(train);

    train = new TransilienTrain();
    train.setMission("BOUGA90");
    trains.add(train);

    model.addAttribute("origin", from);
    model.addAttribute("destination", to);
    model.addAttribute("trains", trains);
    return "departs";
}
```

My departs.jsp :

```
    <c:if test="${not empty trains}">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-1">Départ</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1">Train</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Destination</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="o" items="${trains}">
                <tr>
                    <td>12h38*</td>
                    <td>${o.mission}</td>
                    <td>Paris Nord</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>* Horraires théoriques</p>
    </c:if>
```

My TransilienTrain class has a getter/setter for the mission attribute.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class TransilienTrain {

    private String mission;

    public String getMission() {
        return mission;
    }

    public void setMission(String mission) {
        this.mission = mission;
    }
}
```

When I check the source code of the page, I do have the items in my list, but the o.mission isn't replaced with anything.

Comment: what do you mean when you say you have items in your list when you view the source code of the page?

Comment: In fact reading what you wrote made me realize, it's look like my "trains" object in the jsp is a string array, I have stuff like items="TransilienTrain@someHashCode". So I guess I don't have TransilienTrain objects but String. Any idea why ?
I have :
<c:forEach var="o" items="[com.dar.sncf.data.model.TransilienTrain@2e30a4ad, com.dar.sncf.data.model.TransilienTrain@7b8b718b, com.dar.sncf.data.model.TransilienTrain@7fcb9c0a]">

Comment: Have you imported jstl taglib for jsp core tags in your jsp? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html

Comment: Wow, can't believe I forgot that, I thought I had, but no ! It works fine now, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Thanks to @singh101. 
Forgot to import the taglib definition:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```